# excel vba open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My code is:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
file = Dir("C:\Users\dlf164\Desktop\NE\")
While (file <> "")
    If InStr(file, a) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)

    End If
file = Dir
Wend
```

The error which I am receiving is *Application or object defined  runtime error*.

How to solve this?

Comment: Maybe `file` is not an Excel (compatible) file?

Comment: Its excel compatible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Answer (score 4):

`Dir()` only returns the filename, but `Workbooks.Open()` requires the full path.  Try something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\dlf164\Desktop\NE\"
file = Dir(path)
While (file <> "")
    If InStr(file, a) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & file)
    End If
file = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: @user3764484 Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer (and do so for all your old questions). Under the up/down arrows on the left, there is a check mark sign, click on it to accept.