# Open a Workbook with Path and Filename Stored in String Variables

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\ART REPORT"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If objFile.DateLastModified > varDate Then
strName = objFile.Name
End If
Next

Application.Workbooks strPath.strName.Open, vbNormalNoFocus
```

The above code is to check the folder (strPath) for the latest file saved, store the file name in strName and then open that workbook.

I can't seem to find how i'm supposed to refer to the said file using the variables.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

EDIT: Referring to the answers in the following link didn't solve my problem. I keep getting Error 1004 [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157385/how-to-open-a-workbook-specifying-its-path)

Comment: Can you debug your macro and verify the value of `strPath`? I see you are using `&` for concatenating two strings, but I believe that `&` is a worksheet operator. I believe that within VBA you need to use `+` for concatenating strings. (In VBA`&` is a logical operator which gives `FALSE` in case of non-equal entries)

Comment: @Dominique no, use `&`, it concatenates. It is not a logical operator - `And` is.

Comment: I'm actually using the same code in a different userform and using srtName to update a label caption. That works fine. I'm having trouble with `Application.Workbooks strPath.strName.Open, vbNormalNoFocus`

Comment: @NickRazzleflamm use `Workbooks.Open`. Many examples on SO. Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833126/excel-vba-open-workbook).

Comment: @BigBen `Workbooks.Open strPath.strName, vbNormalNoFocus` throws an 'Invalid Qualifier' error

Comment: You need to read the example - here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157385/how-to-open-a-workbook-specifying-its-path). The path and name are the argument  - `Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strName)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a workbook specifying its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157385/how-to-open-a-workbook-specifying-its-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line
`Application.Workbooks strPath.strName.Open, vbNormalNoFocus`

with this one

`Application.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strName)`

For more options you can pass with Workbook.Open, check the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Also what will happen if you have more than one file for which `objFile.DateLastModified > varDate`? Now you will open the last one in the loop

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. `Application.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strName)` throws an error too. Says "Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed.

Comment: And as for having more than one file in the specified folder, I didn't think of that actually. I have the macro deleting all files in the folder before i reach this point in the execution as a safeguard but i guess that isn't productive.

Comment: It should work. Check (e.g. Debug.Print) what is the value of `strPath & "\" & strName`

Comment: `C:\Users\shaniked\Desktop\REQUIRED FILES\ART REPORT\ART.xls` Immediate window outputs this.. Which is the correct folder and file name. But still getting the error.

Comment: Wait maybe the 'file format doesn't match' error i'm getting when opening ART.xls is keeping the macro from opening it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I don't have problem to open such file (i.e. that display this warning) via VBA.

Comment: Well what do you know i removed the `vbNormalNoFocus` from the line and it works perfectly. But i don't want to lose focus on the active workbook when i open the file.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear to replace the whole line

Comment: Yup. Was a bit confused there. Thanks for your help :)